# Cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

How can I signalize to the borrow checker that my call is not going to yield any "colateral" change to the vector property in this particular case.

```
struct Element {}

struct A {
    b: Vec<Element>,
    count: i32,
}

impl A {
    fn do_thing(&self) {
      // does thing without causing side-effects (ie: do some calculations using self.count)
    }
    
    fn do_thing_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Element> {
       for el in self.b.iter_mut() {
            self.do_thing(); // <-- causes the error
            if condition_is_met {
              return Some(el);
            }
       }
       None
    }
}
```

Otherwise, what might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you want to use iter_mut, and not iter()?

Comment: I want to return a mutable reference for a vector element based on a given condition. I'll update the the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found out a safer way to work around this for those who might be interested. I changed the way the for-loop iterates going on by index. Then I return the corresponding vector element using `Vec::get_mut`.

```
fn do_thing_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Element>  {
   for el in self.b.iter() {
        self.do_thing();
        if condition_is_met {
            return self.b.get_mut(0);
        }
   }
   None
}
```